# Why Does The Camera Make Weird Angles when animated?

Tags: animation

I have a simple animation wherein i show one angle, then switch to another and back. My problem is that the camera makes **big angle change**. How do you do a smooth transition without adding so many **key frames** to let the **subject** stay in frame?

Please see video  [enter link description here](https://youtu.be/DaiG3n1TGls)

I just want the camera to move to **Top View** without zooming in in between frames.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe go int the Properties panel > Data > Shape > Resolution, then increase the Preview U and Render U to smooth your curve. But also note that its shape seems a bit weird but maybe it's what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an **empty** to let camera stick on it (make parent with transform), and rotate the empty to make your camera rotate

[image]
[image]

You only need two keys for this job with a super stable result.

Comment: thank you @hikariztw

Comment: Very nice illustration!